# Passing Array To new Activity

Tags: android

Ok so, I have my app which so far opens a new `Activity` from the SplashScreen. Once this Activity is open there is a button to *add players* which opens up a new `Activty`. In this `Activty` I have an `Array` which will be populated by a `EditText` box.

Once the players have been added the play button will be clicked which will got back to the previous `Activity`.

My question is when the play button is clicked and you go back to the previous `Activty` I need the `Array` to be carried over and populate a `String`.

**CODE UPDATED - No force close now but the array dosent seem to be carrying over and populating `strArray`**

I have this button to carry the `Array` once players have been added:

```
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playnow);
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent( demo.AddRemove.this, demo.play.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putStringArrayList( "KEY", playerList );
i.putExtras( extras );
startActivity( i );

}});
}
```

And this to show the `Array` that was carried over:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (extras == null) {
        strArray = new String[0];
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> myStrings = extras.getStringArrayList("KEY");
        if (myStrings == null) {
            strArray = new String[0];
        } else {
            strArray = (String[]) myStrings.toArray();
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.passw_layout);

    initWheel(R.id.passw_1, strArray);
```

But as I said before When I try to open the first Activty play.java from the SplashScreen it force closes with `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Which I think is because the `extras` is empty.

Comment: Please post this code initWheel(R.id.passw_1, strArray);

Comment: I am not sure if extras its the same as getIntent().getExtras(). Try replacing the call with that. I meant the method, so check if maybe your problem is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] strArray;
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  //Added this
if (extras == null) {
    strArray = new String[0];
} else {
    ArrayList<String> myStrings = extras.getStringArrayList("KEY");
    if (myStrings == null) {
        strArray = new String[0];
    } else {
        strArray = (String[]) myStrings.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: That caused a force close. I just sent you an invite :D

Comment: Great. No problem. I'll join in a moment

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple check for null, and create an empty array:

```
String[] strArray;
if (extras == null) {
    strArray = new String[0];
} else {
    ArrayList<String> myStrings = extras.getStringArrayList("KEY");
    if (myStrings == null) {
        strArray = new String[0];
    } else {
        strArray = (String[]) myStrings.toArray();
    }
}
```

If you don't like such a deeply nested if statement, you could also create a method to extract the array, and use early return to return the array as soon as you find a null value.

Comment: Never mind figuerd that out, but for some reason its not carrying over the array and displaying it? Can you join me in a chat?